# I need to get the subquery column name in where condition

Tags: mysql

This is my query and i need to check sub query column previousenddate in where condition without NULL.

```
SELECT pa.policy_id,
    pa.person_id,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(pas.person_id)
        FROM `package_assignments` pas
        WHERE pas.person_id = pa.person_id
        GROUP BY pas.person_id
        ) AS Member_Count,
    pe.full_name,
    pa.start_date,
    pa.end_date,
    (
        SELECT p.end_date
        FROM `package_assignments` p
        WHERE p.person_id = pa.person_id
        ORDER BY p.end_date DESC LIMIT 1,
            1
        ) previousenddate
FROM `package_assignments` pa,
    persons pe
WHERE end_date BETWEEN "2017-04-01"
        AND "2017-04-30"
    AND pa.person_id = pe.id
    AND pa.rmhc_location = 5006
    AND previousenddate > 1
```

I need to check the previousenddate column without Null For Eg:where previousenddate <> 'NULL'

Comment: Probably to easy to be your solution, but I'll just post it anyways... `and not previousenddate is null` ?

Comment: You might want to check https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp to improve your querrys

Comment: NULL is neither equal nor not equal to anything else - not even NULL!! The test for nullness is IS NULL or IS NOT NULL